# disable or lock mouse and keyboard in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way of disabling or locking mouse and keyboard using python? I want to freeze the mouse and disable the keyboard.

Comment: A `pynput` based script that locks the mouse and keyboard and unlocks them after pressing hotkeys. hotkeys. https://github.com/MrChebur/supress_input

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I haven't tested (actually I've tested the mouse part, and it annoyingly works) but something like this using [pyhook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page) would do what you want:

```
import pythoncom, pyHook 

def uMad(event):
    return False

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = uMad
hm.KeyAll = uMad
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: it works perfectly.. (annoying) lol... my problem now is how to enable it. Do i just change the boolean to True?

Comment: You would have to redefine the `MouseAll` and `KeyAll` with another function that always returns True. Than the keyboard and mouse would be enabled again.

Answer (score 16):

I have extended Fábio Diniz's answer to a class which provides both a block() and an unblock() function which block (selectively) mouse/keyboard inputs. I also added a timeout functionality which (hopefully) addresses the annoyance of locking oneself out.

```
import pyHook 
from threading import Timer
import win32gui
import logging

class blockInput():
    def OnKeyboardEvent(self,event):
        return False

    def OnMouseEvent(self,event):
        return False

    def unblock(self):
        logging.info(" -- Unblock!")
        if self.t.is_alive():
            self.t.cancel()
        try: self.hm.UnhookKeyboard()
        except: pass
        try: self.hm.UnhookMouse()
        except: pass

    def block(self, timeout = 10, keyboard = True, mouse = True):
        self.t = Timer(timeout, self.unblock)
        self.t.start()

        logging.info(" -- Block!")
        if mouse:
            self.hm.MouseAll = self.OnMouseEvent
            self.hm.HookMouse()
        if keyboard:
            self.hm.KeyAll = self.OnKeyboardEvent
            self.hm.HookKeyboard()
        win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages()

    def __init__(self):
        self.hm = pyHook.HookManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    block = blockInput()
    block.block()

    import time
    t0 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t0 < 10:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(time.time() - t0)

    block.unblock()
    logging.info("Done.")
```

You can have a look at the main routine for example usage.

Comment: Why the downvote? The code is working well in quite a number of my automatization scripts. If there is any problem please post a comment or send a message so I can improve it.

Answer (score 14):

For me, just two lines of programming solved the problem:

```
from ctypes import *

ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(True) #enable block

#or 

ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(False) #disable block
```

Comment: Definitly the easiest thing to do, If you are on Windows

Comment: What exactly is windll?

Comment: @Filip it needs to be run as administrator

Comment: @Mr.Che see my comment

Comment: @Eildosa Thank you for your comment! Tested with PyCharm and administrative privileges - everything works! Now I can clean my mouse and keyboard without the danger of accidentally deleting anything. =)

Comment: By the way, this command does not prevent pressing the `Ctrl + Alt + Del` combination.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to opreate it, tried but it seems it doest work

Comment: @ComradeChe Ctrl+Alt+Del is supposed to always work, you cannot block that combo.

Answer (score 7):

Totally different take since all the solutions mentioned above use a quiet outdated library(pyhook) and this pyhook method personally didnt work for me.

```
import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Controller
from time import sleep

def blockinput():
    global block_input_flag
    block_input_flag = 1
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=blockinput_start)
    t1.start()
    print("[SUCCESS] Input blocked!")
    

def unblockinput():
    blockinput_stop()
    print("[SUCCESS] Input unblocked!")
    

    def blockinput_start():
        mouse = Controller()
        global block_input_flag
        for i in range(150):
            keyboard.block_key(i)
        while block_input_flag == 1:
            mouse.position = (0, 0)
    
    def blockinput_stop():
        global block_input_flag
        for i in range(150):
            keyboard.unblock_key(i)
        block_input_flag = 0


blockinput()
print("now blocking")
sleep(5)
print("now unblocking")
```

Comment: This isn't blocking mouse input left click/right click.
It only pushes the pointer to (0, 0) but do you have a solution for blocking mouse input completely?

Comment: +sighclone See my answer for a better way of using pynput and actually blocks mouse input completely. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74182773/12033271

Answer (score 7):

Since 2018, you can now use [pynput (v1.4+)](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to suppress keyboard and mouse events on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

```py
import pynput

# Disable mouse and keyboard events
mouse_listener = pynput.mouse.Listener(suppress=True)
mouse_listener.start()
keyboard_listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(suppress=True)
keyboard_listener.start()

# Enable mouse and keyboard events
mouse_listener.stop()
keyboard_listener.stop()
```

This also disables mouse scrolling and clicking.

However, this does not stop users from pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del on Windows. But you can run the script in an elevated command prompt, and the mouse and keyboard will still be disabled, even if they opened Task Manager using Ctrl+Alt+Delete, so there is no harm done (apparently there are way to actually prevent Ctrl+Alt+Delete, but do your own research for that)

Comment: only answer that worked for me in 2023

Comment: Package: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput

Answer (score 2):

I just slightly modified the @Robert code and instead of the time I used external interrupt to close the program i.e. if you connect any external drive then the program gets close and your mouse and keyboard will be working perfectly.

```
import pyHook 
from threading import Timer
import win32gui
import logging
import win32file

def locate_usb():#this will check any external Drives
    drive_list = []
    drivebits = win32file.GetLogicalDrives()
    # print(drivebits)
    for d in range(1, 26):
        mask = 1 << d
        if drivebits & mask:
            # here if the drive is at least there
            drname = '%c:\\' % chr(ord('A') + d)
            t = win32file.GetDriveType(drname)
            if t == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
            drive_list.append(drname)
    return drive_list

class blockInput():
    def OnKeyboardEvent(self,event):
        return False

    def OnMouseEvent(self,event):
        return False

    def unblock(self):

        try: self.hm.UnhookKeyboard()
        except: pass
        try: self.hm.UnhookMouse()
        except: pass

    def block(self ,keyboard = True, mouse = True):
    
        while(1):
            if mouse:
                  self.hm.MouseAll = self.OnMouseEvent
                  self.hm.HookMouse()
            if keyboard:
                  self.hm.KeyAll = self.OnKeyboardEvent
                  self.hm.HookKeyboard()
            win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages()
            cg= locate_usb()
            if cg:
                break
      

    def __init__(self):
        self.hm = pyHook.HookManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    block = blockInput()
    block.block()
    block.unblock()
```

I hope this code will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyautogui to do this. Though I recommend adding keyboard for making a stopping key. First,  you want to install pyautogui and keyboard.
Please note: this only disables the mouse not the keyboard, that is a very bad idea.

```
pip install pyautogui
pip install keyboard
```

Ok, with that sorted, we have to actually make the disabler.

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

stopKey = "s" #The stopKey is the button to press to stop. you can also do a shortcut like ctrl+s
maxX, maxY = pyautogui.size() #get max size of screen
While True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(stopKey):
        break
    else:
    pyautogui.moveTo(maxX/2, maxY/2) #move the mouse to the center of the screen
```

Ok, but there is 2 ways to get out of this. pressing S, and also quickly moving the mouse to one of the corners of the screen (that is a pyautogui failsafe, but we can disable that). If you want to disable the failsafe, add this after the imports:

```
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
```

Please note that disabling the failsafe is NOT recommended!
Ok, so now the only way to exit is the S key. If you want to stop this somewhere else in your program, do this:

```
 pyautogui.press(stopKey)
```

Ok, so its not perfect, but it will stop you from doing basically anything with your mouse.

Comment: "will stop you from doing basically anything with your mouse". So, are clicks and scrolling also disabled then ?