# Block keyboard and mouse input in python, windows (without pyhook)

Tags: python, windows

So i'm making a stupid rickroll for fun, something unoffensive only to learn python (I am a beginner) and I am wondering how to block the mouse and the keyboard temporarily so you can't close the tabs, but I don't know how. I have seen a few ways to do this, but some of them doesn't even work, and the rest use pyhook, and i've been struggling with downloading it for an hour, but I can't. Is there a way to do that in Windows that still work nowadays without using pyhook? Thanks :).
Also, please let me know if I wrote something wrong (i'm from spain and I don't have a perfect English)

Here is the code of the rickroll:

```
import webbrowser
import time


for i in ("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"):

    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
    time.sleep(2)




print("YOU GOT RICKROLLED HAHAHAHAHA")
```

Comment: It is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838607/block-keyboard-and-mouse-input-in-python-windows-without-pyhook) but requires admin rights.

Comment: @viilpe ok, no problem :)

Comment: I apologize for the wrong link, here is the correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264161/can-python-use-blockinput

Comment: @viilpe ok, thanks! I posted a comment asking for the link 6 seconds before you wrote the comment, but i just deleted it hahaha. I gonna check that!