# How to temporarily disable keyboard input using Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I'm writing a simple program for Windows using Python, and this program takes advantage of the `time` module. Specifically, I'm using `time.sleep(x)` to pause the program for a short moment, generally 0.5-2 seconds. Here's basically what I'm doing:

```
import time
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    x = input(prompt)
    if x == 'spam':
        break
```

The problem with this is, if the user presses enter while `time.sleep` has it paused, then those enters will be counted towards the input in the `while` loop. This results in `prompt` being printed several times, which is frustrating.

I want to know if there's a way to temporarily disable keyboard input while `time.sleep` is going on, and then enable it afterwards. Something like this:

```
import time
disable_keyboard_input()
time.sleep(2)
enable_keyboard_input()

while True:
    etc.
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this using Python? Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520893/how-to-flush-the-input-stream-in-python pretty much a duplicate

Comment: @Maltysen That method didn't work for me :(

Comment: `while msvcrt.kbhit(): msvcrt.getwch()` should work to clear the keyboard buffer after sleeping. The caveat is that this only works when `stdin` is the Windows console, not in development environments that replace `sys.stdin` with a pipe or file-like object.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you so much, that worked! I didn't try running it through the console because I didn't know that it changed how `sys.stdin` worked. It works perfectly now, thank you so much! :D

Comment: Also a duplicate of [disable or lock mouse and keyboard in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529991/disable-or-lock-mouse-and-keyboard-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

I found this worked brilliantly:

```
import time
class keyboardDisable():

    def start(self):
        self.on = True

    def stop(self):
        self.on = False

    def __call__(self): 
        while self.on:
            msvcrt.getwch()


    def __init__(self):
        self.on = False
        import msvcrt

disable = keyboardDisable()
disable.start()
time.sleep(10)
disable.stop()
```

It stops the user from typing anything; when you press a key on the keyboard, nothing happens.

Comment: I integrated this code in one of my programs and it is really useful.  My question is, exactly how does it work?

Comment: @pythonier500 first of all, sorry for the late reply. The code works by constantly running msvcrt.getwch(), which returns the key pressed before the character is printed on screen. Generally, this would be used in code where the character is printed after being modified somehow, but in this case the value returned is ignored. If you were to instead print it, you would be able to type normally. TLRD: It intercepts the key before it is displayed

Comment: Does the code above generally disables the input from keyboard, or only in a shell or cmd ? Moreover if I understand well the result that we want to get is to disable ANY input from keyboard for 10 seconds.

Comment: It only works within the shell/cmd of python, and only works to stop characters being displayed there. If you want to stop all keyboard input, thats much harder. It just makes python ignore keypresses, which solves OP's problem

Comment: Okk thanks @mono , I am trying to suppress not stop the keyboard input if a specific condition is True, but struggling a lot.

Comment: I don't see how `__call__` is called. The object is called `disable` but there is no call to `disable()`. If I do call it, it hangs forever, because it's in the endless while loop

Answer (score 3):

The other 2 answers are perfect if you are using it to make a real software and want to disable keyboard input only in the output screen. However, if it's for personal usage or you want to disable the keyboard for the whole system, you can use this code:

```
import keyboard
import time
a = int(input("Enter the time (in seconds) for which you want to disable keyboard: "))
for i in range(150):
    keyboard.block_key(i)
time.sleep(a)
```

Don't forget to run `pip install keyboard` in the terminal before executing this code otherwise, you will get an error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
time.sleep(2)

sys.stdout = stdout

while True:
    pass
```

Didn't tried this. But I hope all that was typed before sleep is ended will sended to stderr... Don't sure, but maybe Python have access to linux's std/null?