# Python keyboard events - Hide user input and send keys to buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

Hi,
I am working on a project and I am monitoring the keyboard with the keyboard module.
My application works in real-time (on-the-fly) and read strings entered from user (with the keyboard module as mentioned) 
What I want to do is hide user input when some specific conditions are True.
I have searched all the web and didn't manage to find something that does what I want.
To give it a more detailed explanation lets say that the user enters some text and this text string-by-string is being checked for some condition from my program. 
If everything is OK, then nothing happens but if not, then I want the next user input not to be shown in the position he is writing.
I found solutions that do exactly this in the terminal like the msvcrt module ([How to temporarily disable keyboard input using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289945/how-to-temporarily-disable-keyboard-input-using-python) ) or do the above functionality with the input() function.
Is there something that prevent the text ,entered from the keyboard, from showing to the screen, but send it to a buffer for editing first.
Thanks in advance.

! I am on windows

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529991/disable-or-lock-mouse-and-keyboard-in-python

Comment: The solutions there don't work. Thanks for the answer though.