# How to disable or ignore python input in the console? on Mac

Tags: python, macos, console, keyboard

I see a lot of answers to this question online, but the only [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48093769/16960479) I have found uses the msvcrt module that (as I understand it) is only available for Windows.

I am making a simple python console game and I want to stop the user from typing anything while the application is loading or playing a simple animation as it tends to break the program.

Example:

```
import time


#disable input here
print('hi')
time.sleep(3)
print('3 seconds have gone by')
#enable input
```

I don't want to let the user roll their face over the keyboard and make everything messy and ugly. I know mac is very strict about this kind of stuff, is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

From the solution you linked I can see that you are only needing the `msvcrt.getwch()` function, so you could use the one from the [`getch`](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) module i.e. `getch.getch()`.