# How do I disable the keyboard after a time?

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard, python-multithreading

I want that, while the program is running, all the keys I type are ignored. In a simple example, the problem I want to solve is the following.

```
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
```

If I type something during those 5 seconds, whatever I wrote will appear when that time is up. In this case, it will be displayed in the command line.

This affects me when creating multiple threads, where one is dedicated to printing several times over several seconds, and when it finishes, the other thread takes an input. In another simple example, it would be similar to this:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(5) # If I type something here and press 'Enter', right after the 5 seconds, the input will auto-fill
entry = input('Write something: ')
```

I searched for any library could make that task but didn't found nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to temporarily disable keyboard input using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289945/how-to-temporarily-disable-keyboard-input-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

This demo code will collect input from the keyboard in the first 5 seconds.

```py
import msvcrt
import time

def user_input(timeout):
    print("You have 5 seconds to input something:")
    start_time = time.time()

    input_text = ""
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            char = msvcrt.getch().decode("utf-8")
            if char == '\r':
                break
            input_text += char

        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - start_time > timeout:
            print("\nTime's up!")
            return input_text if input_text else None

    return input_text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = user_input(5)
    if result is not None:
        print("You entered:", result)
```