# Hook Mouse clicks and intercept them

Tags: python, mouseevent

I am currently trying to stop mouse clicks while my Script is running and still work with them.
If you are confused about the use case I will elaborate at the end of the question.

Currently I can get clicks like this:

```
import mouse
import time

def mouseHook(event):
    if type(event) == mouse.ButtonEvent:
        print(event)

mouse.hook(mouseHook)
while 1:
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

But this still lets the clicks go through, how would I intercept them?

*use case: simulate a monitor and while mouse is on that monitor send all movements, clicks and keypresses to MacBook (similar to Synergy, Mouse without Borders or Share Mouse)*

Answer (score 0):

The hook used by the application only 'hooks' into the process, which means it gets information from it, but can't insert or modify it's code.

For reference on windows that would use (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644988(v=vs.85))

The easiest way would be to have your application ignore the mouseclicks.

Comment: I am trying to intercept them not only on my application but in general on that monitor.

Comment: You'd have to check whether the mouse or your OS provides an interface for that. Or you have an application capture it, move it somewhere else and simulate your own cursor

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pynput** to create a hook on the mouse and then we can block all movement of the mouse like this

```html
import pynput, keyboard

# Disable mouse
mouse_listener = pynput.mouse.Listener(suppress=True)
mouse_listener.start()


# Re-Enable mouse
mouse_listener.stop()
```

And to intercept the presses we use this:

```html
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529991/disable-or-lock-mouse-and-keyboard-in-python

import pynput, keyboard

def onMove(x, y, mouse:pynput.mouse.Button, pressed):
    print(x, y, mouse.name, pressed)


# Disable mouse and keyboard events
mouse_listener = pynput.mouse.Listener(on_click=onMove, suppress=True)
mouse_listener.start()

# Enable mouse and keyboard events

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        mouse_listener.stop()
        break
```

***PLEASE NOTE***
When this is run it will suppress all mouse events and you won't be able to use it so to exit press "q" to stop the program.