# How do I disable and enable keyboard input in Python for Windows?

Tags: python, input, keyboard

Hi im currently working on a triggerbot for Valorant (I don’t wanna cheat i just want to learn python coding and combine it with Pixel detection and input making) and want to ask how i disable the Keyboard input and enable it right after an other task. Something like this:

```
Import mouse
Import keyboard

//diable keyboard here
Mouse.click(„left“)
//enable keyboard here
```

This is just a cut of the Programm if the rest is required i can add this of course.

I tried finding something about it but it didn’t work for me.
I would appreciate help.
Sorry for my maybe bad English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable or lock mouse and keyboard in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529991/disable-or-lock-mouse-and-keyboard-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyautogui library to block keyboard input temporarily. Then, after completing the desired task, you can enable it again.

```
import pyautogui

# Disable keyboard input
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

# Perform your task
pyautogui.click('left')

# Enable keyboard input
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress keyboard input using built-in (standard) Python modules.

It is common to also want to suppress signals while keyboard input is blocked. Therefore, this utility class facilitates that too (by default).

```
from termios import tcgetattr, tcsetattr, TCSAFLUSH
from sys import stdin
from tty import setraw
import signal


class Blocker:
    def __init__(self, ignore_signals=True):
        self._ignore_signals = ignore_signals

    @staticmethod
    def siglist():
        signames = [
            "SIGABRT",
            "SIGINT",
            "SIGTERM",
            "SIGBREAK",
            "SIGALRM",
            "SIGCONT",
            "SIGHUP",
            "SIGUSR1",
            "SIGUSR2",
            "SIGWINCH",
        ]
        _siglist = []
        for signame in signames:
            if (sig := getattr(signal, signame, None)) is not None:
                _siglist.append(sig)
        return _siglist

    def __enter__(self):
        self._fd = stdin.fileno()
        self._attr = tcgetattr(self._fd)
        setraw(self._fd)
        if self._ignore_signals:
            self._sigfuncs = {
                s: signal.signal(s, signal.SIG_IGN) for s in Blocker.siglist()
            }
        else:
            self._sigfuncs = None
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        if self._sigfuncs is not None:
            for kv in self._sigfuncs.items():
                signal.signal(*kv)
        if self._attr is not None:
            tcsetattr(self._fd, TCSAFLUSH, self._attr)


import time
# during sleep, keyboard input and observable signals will be ignored
with Blocker():
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `keyboard` module, we can block every key on the keyboard:

```
import keyboard

for key in range(150): #150 should be enough for all the keys on the keyboard
    keyboard.block_key(key) #block the key until unblocked

#do stuff

for key in range(150):
    keyboard.unblock_key(key) #unblocks all the keys
```

To make this a little easier and readable in your program, you could create two simple functions for it:

```
import keyboard

def block():
    for key in range(150):
        keyboard.block_key(key)

def unblock():
    for key in range(150):
        keyboard.unblock_key(key)

block()
#do stuff
unblock()
```